# How to track change in textbox using jQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-events

I want to check if user changes the value of a textbox.  If the user changes the value, then I want to display the changed value in a different textbox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jquery has an event for this, [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/), this event will detect content changes when the textbox looses focus.

If you are wanting to detect the change at *every* keypress, [`.keyup()`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) and [`.keydown()`](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/) might be better suited for your needs.

Examples for your intended use:

```
//just change '.change' to '.keyup' or '.keydown' the rest is the same.
$('input').change(function() {
    $('target').val(this.value);
});
```

Comment: Jondavidjohn's answer is correct. I'd like to add that the change event is raised only if the text box's value is truly changed. So if the value is changed from "A", "B" it will fire. But then if it is changed back to "A" it may not (depending on whether the value of the text box was pre-populated with "A" or not when the form was rendered by the browser.

Comment: this is good solution, but i have several input textboxes. is there any trick to send changed data from any of existing textboxes into the target textbox, without repeating the code?